# Always display vote split

Tags: support, feature-request

Since I made it to 1k reputation (yay!), I can now see the vote split by clicking on the current vote status of a question or answer. Is there any way so that I can always see these when I am logged in (so that I need not click it every time)

Comment: Not tried it, but there's a grease monkey script on stackapps: http://stackapps.com/questions/6153/auto-load-vote-counts

Comment: @Mokubai, will give it a try, but I had hoped there would be a setting for this...

Comment: No. Typically you don't need to care enough to know for *every* post and it is mainly just visual clutter.